# Deployment files filled with zero bytes in CLion Deployment

Tags: ssh, clion, jetbrains-ide, corruption

I am trying to upload file to remote machine with Deployment feature, but it corrupts them, filling with zero bytes.

What can be wrong?

---

This is happening with only one remote machine. Deploying onto another ones goes normal. So, it is some interference between machine config and Jetbrains config/bugs.

---

SFTP put works fine on the same machine.

---

If I create Russian characters directory in `/root` folder, I get the following error when I am listing `/root` folder:

```
2019-06-24 17:06:49,443 [  25890]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - cd "/" 
2019-06-24 17:06:49,459 [  25906]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - stat "root" 
2019-06-24 17:06:49,467 [  25914]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - drwx------ 0 0 4096 Mon Jun 24 17:05:39 MSK 2019, mtime 1,561,385,139 
2019-06-24 17:06:49,469 [  25916]   WARN - i.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode - Could not list the contents of folder "sftp://cmnanny/root". 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of folder "sftp://cmnanny/root".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:1101)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.DeploymentPathUtils.getChildren(DeploymentPathUtils.java:373)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode$1.compute(ServerTreeNode.java:250)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode$1.compute(ServerTreeNode.java:247)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool$RemoteConnectionImpl.executeServerOperation(RemoteConnectionPool.java:141)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.getChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:247)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.createChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:206)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.loadChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:166)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.lambda$getChildren$0(ServerTreeNode.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: 4: Failure
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1633)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1553)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.config.LoggingSftpChannel.ls(LoggingSftpChannel.java:215)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileObject.doListChildrenResolved(SftpFileObject.java:495)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:1091)
```

The machine host name contains special chars like # and &, may be they are confusing CLion parser?